# SSRS Passing parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a column in my table which consists of email id separated by semi colon

**email_id**

```
xx.gmal.com;yy.gmail.com
xx.gmal.com;yy.gmail.com;zz.gmail.com
xx.gmal.com;
yy.gmail.com;zz.gmail.com
```

I need to pass this column as multi-valued parameter. I need to separate column such that it contains single e-mail per column and parameter has to use that column and if I select multiple parameter values, it has to show that rows which has that email id.

In main query, when I use  email_id in (@email_id) its not working and when I used `like` operator it is not working. It works for single one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass this as a multi-value parameter as it is simply one text field. Try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE @email_id LIKE '%' + email_id + '%'
```

Comment: I need to pass it as multi valued one... like operator works fine if I select single email id but it fails for multiple email ids